# How can I get a Copyright Transfer Form without notifying my advisor?

Tags: advisor, conference, copyright, program-committee

My case is that we already have an adviser. She's not allowing us to register for conference (rank B). We have prepared everything after getting acceptance letter. Now she's telling us to submit the work to another conference (ranks A*)! We are pretty much sure our paper will surely be rejected if we submit it there and since our undergraduate study will be completed within 2 months we may not ever get this chance to publish a paper!

What should i do? She's simply not ready to listen. As she was the one submitting everything program committee will send eCF to her only. Should I write to the program committee so that he sends me an eCF? I don't want to change author names... just want to publish the paper!

Comment: Is she a co-author of your paper? If so, do not try to circumvent her; it would be unethical to submit anywhere that she does not agree to. Why is it so important that you get the paper accepted somewhere before you graduate?

Comment: What do you mean by *We*? Are you Msc or Phd ?

Comment: Suppose you got the copyright form. It is going to say something like "For jointly authored Works, all joint authors should sign, or one of the authors should sign as authorized agent for the others." [IEEE COPYRIGHT AND CONSENT FORM](http://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecopyrightform.pdf). How do you plan to get the professor to either sign, or authorize you to sign as her agent?

Comment: Have you tried explaining your situation to your professor? This sounds just as likely to be a communication breakdown as it is a disagreement.

Comment: What benefit do you expect from a paper published in a lower-ranked conference that you would not also get from one in submission, on your professor's advice, to a top ranked one?

Comment: Life is full of risk. It can't be avoided. A top-ranked conference is far more likely to accept a completely original paper than a warmed-over version of something already published. If you did not have your professor's consent before submitting the paper, you took an enormous risk.

Comment: If you are thinking of submitting to both, read [Can a conference paper be an extended version of a previous conference paper? Will it face copyright issues?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/23114/10220)

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  You must have had your advisor/coauthor's permission to submit the paper to the first conference.  Right?  But why would she give that permission if she had no intention of letting you actually publish there?

Comment: I'm also confused. Do I understand you correctly that the paper has already been accepted at the first conference? If so, submitting it elsewhere is a really bad idea - is your advisor saying you should do this?

Comment: There is one key question that may be contributing to confusion: Did the professor consent to submitting the paper to the conference where it has been accepted?

Answer (score 9):

This makes me sick (sorry). While I may understand your motivation and enthusiasm. But   *betraying* your co-author is not an acceptable solution. All co-authors need to agree on when and where to submit. Most likely, *she knows better than you where the work should go*. Moreover, If you planning to continue research after graduation it is better to keep good relation with her (at least you will need a recommendation letter written by her). You can continue your hidden game but no one would guarantee the outcome. She may even ruin your graduation. **You need to have an honest discussion with her and make a decision**. Tell her why you want to publish. No games. People tend to publish years after doing research/graduation.

Comment: You keeping her as a co-author. And co-authors have responsibilities and rights. Publishing without their consents is what I see as betraying them. You may go along the copyright thing. But still this is not ethical.

Comment: Even if your PI were not a co-author many research facilities will most certainly file internal documents ("permit of publication") to confirm that the publication follows the code of conduct/ethical code (or whatever your institution claims to follow). Those are typically to be signed by the PI. Failure to follow this is not just betrayal but may earn you a written dissuasion. Most certainly not the way to start a scientific carrier.